# CALayer position contains NaN

Tags: uitableview, switch-statement, swift2, xcode7, calayer

I had my app running properly, but on my setting VC I was using a lot of `if indexPath.row == aGivenRowNumber{ ...}`, I try to refactor it using a `switch indexPath.row {...}` , but now the app start crashing with this error: `'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [75.75 nan]'` which from what I read happens when you have a divide by zero in the code, however my app was working just fine before I try doing the `switch` . This is not the first time it is happening, last time I tried using the switch pattern in TableViewController same thing happened but I couldn't make the connection with the `switch` pattern then. But this time around, refactoring from `if ...then` to `switch ... case` is the only thing I did as I started working. Can anybody tell me what this is happening and how to fix the problem now? I am using swift and Xcode 7.2 
Thank you

edit: I tried to revert back to the previous working state using version control, but the app just keeps crashing now

update: It looks like when I load the app on the physical device it works fine. So, maybe this is a problem with the simulator ... but I don't know if putting back the switch statement will make it crash on the device as well, I don't want to try...

Comment: please post the switch statement so we can see